# Is it able, to embed the font, in the css style sheet , instead of defining font on every web page?

Tags: html, css, fonts

Now what i have done is,

embed this font to html page

```
<style type="text/css">
    @font-face 
    { 
        font-family: AvenirNext LT Pro Regular; 
        src: url(font/AvenirNextLTPro-Regular.otf); 
    }
</style>
```

what i done is , on the header of the html, i got a master css sheet to apply to all web page which is

```
<link href="Styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

The thing is, if i use the font face code and insert into style.css, all the webpage is unable to use the font, now currently i am required to keep adding the font face on every web page so the webpage can be use the font directly, is there is a way that if i insert the font face into style.css, so every webpage can use the font directly from style.css? so i am not required to insert the font face on every webpage

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your case is the relative path name.

In stylesheets, paths are relative to the location of the stylesheet itself, so if the font is located in

`yourdomain/font/AvenirNextLTPro-Regular.otf`

and the stylesheet is located in

`yourdomain/Styles/style.css`

then in the stylesheet you will have to write

`../font/AvenirNextLTPro-Regular.otf`

to access it.

Comment: dude, i am not able to access it when i changes to

    font-family: AvenirNext LT Pro Regular; 
    src: url(../font/AvenirNextLTPro-Regular.otf); 

and i checked my path contained that file

Comment: Hm. Can you provide a link to your site? Maybe something else goes wrong.

Comment: Hi lister, my website havent migrate yet, this is still under development stage

Comment: i am even put my full path as this

    font-family: AvenirNext LT Pro Regular; 
    src: url(C:/Users/user/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/WebSites/WebSite1/font/AvenirNextLTPro-Regular.otf); 

and this not working